# Error in MySQL code

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
CREATE TABLE EventStaff (
     eventID INTEGER,
     staffID INTEGER,
     FOREIGN KEY eventID REFERENCES Event(eventID),
     FOREIGN KEY staffID REFERENCES Staff(staffID),
     PRIMARY KEY(eventID, staffID)
 );
```

this table is coming up with this error when trying to insert into my database:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES Event(eventID),
FOREIGN KEY staffID REFERENCES Staff(staffID),
PRIMAR' at line 4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [syntax for foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) requires parentheses around the column name:

```
FOREIGN KEY (eventID) REFERENCES Event(eventID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah ... you are missing `()` like

```
FOREIGN KEY (eventID) REFERENCES Event(eventID),
            ^....... Here
```

Also it's easier to refer [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) when in doubt